# Using OpenFileDialog w/ a relative path as initialDirectory

Tags: c#, directory, relative-path, openfiledialog

I'd like to give the appropriate value to Initial directory, so it would open the folder (called "Images") which I created in my project.
I must use a relative path, so my program works not depending on the computer I work .
But the problem is I don't know how to access this folder...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use:

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,
@"YourSubDirectoryName");
```

**Edit:** or try this if you prefer... are you in windows forms?

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"YourSubDirectoryName");
```

**Edit 2 for WPF:**

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

... from the Microsoft Forums...

Comment: My application doesn't have any StartupPath... :/

Comment: (this is a wpf application, i m actually looking for something giving the startupPath in wpf)

Comment: In fact, I am not sure this is what I need because I want to use files that are in a resources folder. 
I already sused this kind of path : /myProject;component/blabla but I don't remember exactly how it works...
Do you know what I mean?

Comment: then decide what you need and edit your question :-) if files are in the file system inside a subfolder of the app folder you can use the approach I suggested, if those files are embedded resources included "inside" the .exe file you need to load the resources from there with a completely different approach ;-)

Comment: GetDirectoryName + Assembly.GetEntryAssembly is best.

Comment: Yes you're right, I didn't have the good approach!
I used your method + a copy of the files I need and it works great, thanks!

Comment: @DavidePiras sir i am importing the background image from the system resources so i want to replace that with the new image from the open file dialog and bring that image in the resource folder with the same name. how can i do that?

Comment: hmm... System.IO.Path.Combine seems to call for a ParamArray of strings. for (VB.NET), OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine({Application.StartupPath, "SubdirectoryName"})..

Comment: Also, a minor note, make sure you have files in the folder for it to be included.. content files should be specified to be 'copied to output' through property window. It doesn't do it by default..