# Get relative path from OpenFileDialog in C#

Tags: c#, relative-path, openfiledialog

I am a beginner at programing and I´m writing my second Prog.
I have a Question about how to get a relative path to my application Startup path.
The Program reads an .xml-file that has a path of a .jpg stored in it. It creates a Picturebox for every path and loads the respective image.
The problem I have is, that I have the images in my Dropbox to be able to use the Program on any PC that has Dropbox. When I use the OpenFileDialog on my main PC and save the Path of the .jpg to the xml it won´t work on my laptop because the Dropbox folder is on another drive as on my main PC.

Does anyone have an idea, how to get around this Problem?

Comment: can you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416605/using-openfiledialog-w-a-relative-path-as-initialdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue, This will get the current location of your application

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

You can do a simple replace of the path.

Example :

```
String JPG_Path_Relative = openFileDialog1.FileName.Replace(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!
Summary:
1. save the image path with your line which would give me "/images/mypic.jpg"
2. Load the path from the xml and add Directory.getCurrentDirectory() infront of it
3. Load the picturebox with the combined string which gives me "D:/users/username/dropbox/myprogram/images/mypic.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

When the dropbox folder is in the default location (User-folder) you can use this to get your path:

```
string userFolderPath= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

This will give C:\Users\USERNAME (drive may be different).
Then simply add the rest of the path to your image folder.

```
string imageFolderPath = userFolderPath + @"\Dropbox\Imagefolder";
```